# "Snapping" when in RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8, xen

I am using mstsc.exe version 6.0 (Remote Desktop non-Metro version) from an XP machine and cannot get Windows 8 in a Xen VM snapping to work.  I can drag a metro app window to the left or right, but it doesn't stick, it just bounces back to full screen.  The snap bars do not appear.

The client PC has two monitors, each with a resolution of 1280x1024.  While mstsc.exe 6.0 does have an option to use both monitors simultaneously in normal settings, I am launching it with spanning enabled:

```
mstsc.exe /span
```

So the effective resolution in the session is 2560x1024.

Is there a trick to getting this to work over RDP?

Comment: Is the resolution at least 1366x768 (client screen)?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Can you give more details?

Comment: Wait, 6.0? Is this on XP? If not, you should get an updated version.

Comment: @Bob Additional details about the environment

Comment: @Bob Yeah, this is XP, but surely W8 is what decides whether snapping should work - why would it care that the client is older provided there is enough real estate for two windows?

Comment: What happens if you snap something locally, lock the Win8 machine, then connect via RDP? Does it stay snapped? (it should)

Comment: The client can make a difference, it's impossible to say for sure. It's possible that Snapping requires a certain level of graphics capability - note that Aero Glass support was only added with RDP 7.0!

Comment: @Bob But Windows 8 removed Aero.

Comment: @CalebJares The point remains: mstsc 6.0 may be lacking support. In any case, I've just verified that it works with `mstsc /w:1366 /h:768` on mstsc 6.1, WinXP, so that does not appear to be the case. Paul, try specifying width and height rather than span?

Comment: @Bob Yeah, it doesn't work with w x h either, so perhaps it is a client issue.  I'll test on a 6.1 client.

Comment: @Bob Ok, it doesn't work with 6.1 either, but I realised that I hadn't taken into consideration that it was running in a VM, with a basic graphics card.  I suspect this is the reason.